# accidentally upgraded to ubuntu 14.04, LiveCD and USB not working to reinstall 10.04 - macbook 4.1

Tags: 14.04, 10.04, macbook

I have a macbook 4.1.

Accidentally upgraded to 14.04. Lots of bugs (no wifi, trackpad is stiff, DVD/CD doesn't work,  etc). None of the terminal sudo codes are working for me...

I think i need to reinstall back to 10.04 but can't get LiveCD or USB to work.

Computer can read USBs, but not when I bootup for some reason. CDs do not work. They spin then get spit back out.

What do I do? I'm trapped!

Please help,

Comment: By now **10.04** may be too old. There is *no further support*, and you would be on your own. However, I think people have successfully run **12.04** on that vintage of MacBook. Look at some the Q/As for search term: **macbook 12.04**